# Java Swing - Paint to canvas created in other class

Tags: java, swing, java-2d, paintcomponent, chess

**Note: ** I'm new here. If you're going to downvote please tell me why.

I'm writing a java chess program using swing. I'm able to display the board, initialize pieces, and store them in a two dimensional array. However, I can't figure out how to display the pieces on my canvas. I keep getting a null pointer error on line 65 of class Piece.

**Update: ** I've included some of the suggested changes. The null pointer error has cleared up, but I'm still having trouble getting the pieces to display. I don't think I've correctly pointed them at the canvas I created in class Chess.

My program is broken into three classes as follows:

Class Chess

```
   import java.util.Scanner;

    import javax.swing.*;
    //import java.awt.*;


    public class Chess {
        public static final int WINDOW_WIDTH=600;
        public static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT=600;
        public static final int SQUARE_WIDTH = (WINDOW_WIDTH-10)/8;
        public static final int SQUARE_HEIGHT = (WINDOW_HEIGHT-40)/8;

        public static int position[][] = {};

        public BoardComponent mycanvas= new BoardComponent(this);

        public Chess()
        {

            JFrame mywindow;
            mywindow=new JFrame("ChessMaster 2012");
            mywindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            mywindow.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

            //BoardComponent mycanvas= new BoardComponent(this);    
            mywindow.add(mycanvas);
            mywindow.setVisible(true);              //window appears here
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            position = new int [8][8];

            new Chess();
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Piece extends JPanel{

    Piece[]  mypiece;

    public ImageIcon piece; 
    int nextID = 0;
    BoardComponent board;
    Chess chess;
    public int locx, locy;

    public void setCanvas(BoardComponent board)
    {
        this.board=board;
    }

    public Piece(char color, char Type, int posX, int posY){
        // each piece assigned a PK on creation, beginning sequentially from top left 
        // and looping back to the beginning of each row
        int pieceID = nextID;
        char pieceColor = color;
        char pieceType = Type;

        posX = locx;
        posY = locy;

        // P = pawn, K = knight, R = Rook, B = Bishop, Q = Queen, 
        //S = king (can't reuse K, so we use S instead)
        if (pieceType == 'P'){
            new Pawn(pieceColor);
        }
        else if (pieceType == 'K'){
            new Knight(pieceColor);
        }
        else if (pieceType == 'R'){
            new Rook(pieceColor);
        }
        else if (pieceType == 'B'){
            new Bishop(pieceColor);
        }
        else if (pieceType == 'Q'){
            new Queen(pieceColor);
        }
        else if (pieceType == 'S'){
            new King(pieceColor);
        }
        nextID ++;
        Chess.position[posX][posY] = pieceID;
        setCanvas(board);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawPiece(g);
    }

    public void drawPiece(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(piece.getImage(),(locx*Chess.SQUARE_WIDTH),(locy*Chess.SQUARE_HEIGHT),null);

    }

    public class Pawn{

        public Pawn(char color){
            if(color == 'w'){
                piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/wpawn.gif");
            }
            else{
                piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/bpawn.gif");
            }
        }
    }   

    public class Knight{

        public Knight(char color){
            if(color == 'w'){
                piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/wknight.gif");
            }
            else{
                piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/bknight.gif");
            }
        }
    }   

    public class Rook{
        public Rook(char color){
            if(color == 'w'){
                piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/wrook.gif");
            }
            else{
                piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/brook.gif");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Bishop{
        public Bishop(char color){
            if(color == 'w'){
                piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/wbishop.gif");
            }
            else{
                piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/bbishop.gif");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Queen{
        public Queen(char color){
            if(color == 'w'){
                piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/wqueen.gif");
            }
            else{
                piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/bqueen.gif");
            }
    }
    }

    public class King{
        public King(char color){
            if(color == 'w'){
                piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/wking.gif");
            }
            else{
                piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/bking.gif");
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

Class BoardComponent:

```
    import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

//This class draws the board and places the initial pieces
public class BoardComponent extends JComponent{
    Chess chess;

    public BoardComponent(Chess chessobject)
    {
        super();
        chess=chessobject;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int rowCount = 0;
    int highCount = 0;
    int wideCount = 0;
    int squareCount = 0;
    ImageIcon piece;
    for(rowCount = 0; rowCount<8;rowCount++){

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            if(squareCount%2==1){
                g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            }
            else{
                g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
            }
            g.fillRect(wideCount,highCount, Chess.SQUARE_WIDTH-5, Chess.SQUARE_HEIGHT-5);
            squareCount = squareCount + 1;
            wideCount = wideCount + Chess.SQUARE_WIDTH;
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
        }
        squareCount +=1;
        wideCount = 0;
        highCount = highCount + Chess.SQUARE_HEIGHT;
    }
    }
}
```

Class Piece:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Piece extends JPanel{

Piece[]  mypiece;

public ImageIcon piece; 
int nextID = 0;
BoardComponent board;
Chess chess;
public int locx, locy;

public void setCanvas(BoardComponent board)
{
    this.board=board;
}

public Piece(char color, char Type, int posX, int posY){
    // each piece assigned a PK on creation, beginning sequentially from top left 
    // and looping back to the beginning of each row
    int pieceID = nextID;
    char pieceColor = color;
    char pieceType = Type;

    posX = locx;
    posY = locy;

    // P = pawn, K = knight, R = Rook, B = Bishop, Q = Queen, 
    //S = king (can't reuse K, so we use S instead)
    if (pieceType == 'P'){
        new Pawn(pieceColor);
    }
    else if (pieceType == 'K'){
        new Knight(pieceColor);
    }
    else if (pieceType == 'R'){
        new Rook(pieceColor);
    }
    else if (pieceType == 'B'){
        new Bishop(pieceColor);
    }
    else if (pieceType == 'Q'){
        new Queen(pieceColor);
    }
    else if (pieceType == 'S'){
        new King(pieceColor);
    }
    nextID ++;
    Chess.position[posX][posY] = pieceID;
    setCanvas(board);
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    drawPiece(g);
}

public void drawPiece(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(piece.getImage(),(locx*Chess.SQUARE_WIDTH),(locy*Chess.SQUARE_HEIGHT),null);

}

public class Pawn{

    public Pawn(char color){
        if(color == 'w'){
            piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/wpawn.gif");
        }
        else{
            piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/bpawn.gif");
        }
    }
}   

public class Knight{

    public Knight(char color){
        if(color == 'w'){
            piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/wknight.gif");
        }
        else{
            piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/bknight.gif");
        }
    }
}   

public class Rook{
    public Rook(char color){
        if(color == 'w'){
            piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/wrook.gif");
        }
        else{
            piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/brook.gif");
        }
    }
}

public class Bishop{
    public Bishop(char color){
        if(color == 'w'){
            piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/wbishop.gif");
        }
        else{
            piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/bbishop.gif");
        }
    }
}

public class Queen{
    public Queen(char color){
        if(color == 'w'){
            piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/wqueen.gif");
        }
        else{
            piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/bqueen.gif");
        }
}
}

public class King{
    public King(char color){
        if(color == 'w'){
            piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/wking.gif");
        }
        else{
            piece = new ImageIcon("src/gfx/bking.gif");
        }
    }
}

}
```

I'm fairly new to java, and this is really throwing me for a loop. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting the Null Pointer error? Be more specific.

Comment: Line 65 of Class Piece. It's commented in the code, but I'll edit the post too.

Comment: It's hard for me to figure out what line 65 is. Can you point it out with a comment in the code?

Comment: It's in there. Here's the relevant block:
       `Graphics g;
        g = board.getGraphics(); // null pointer here
        g.drawImage(piece.getImage(),(locx*Chess.SQUARE_WIDTH),(locy*Chess.SQUARE_HEIGHT),null);`

Answer (score 3):

- Dont call `drawPiece()` from your constructor for what reason? I think [`repaint()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint%28%29) might be what you need.
- dont use `getGraphics()` as it wont be initialized yet until the panel is added and first repaint is done if im not mistaken.
- Also never forget to honor paint chain and have `super.paintComponent(..)` as your first call in your overridden `paintComponent(..)` method of panel.
- Rather extend `JPanel` and not `JComponent`

I think you meant to call `drawPiece()` in `paintComponent(..)` in which place you should just pass the `Graphic`s object to `drawPiece()` from `paintComponent(..)` like so:

```
public class Piece extends JPanel{



    public Piece(char color, char Type, int posX, int posY){

        // each piece assigned a PK on creation, beginning sequentially from top left 
        // and looping back to the beginning of each row
        ....

        // P = pawn, K = knight, R = Rook, B = Bishop, Q = Queen, 
        //S = king (can't reuse K, so we use S instead (from Shah, the historical name)) 
        ....
            nextID ++;
            Chess.position[posX][posY] = pieceID;
            repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawPiece(g);
    }

    public void drawPiece(Graphics g){
        g.drawImage(piece.getImage(),(locx*Chess.SQUARE_WIDTH),(locy*Chess.SQUARE_HEIGHT),null);
    }
}
```

Other suggestions:

- Create `JFrame` and other Swing components on [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) by wrapping UI creation code in

  ```
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
      @Override 
      public void run() {
         //create ui here
      }
  });
  ```
- Dont call `setSize(...)` on `JFrame`

rather override `JPanel` `getPreferredSize()` and return an appropriate size which fits components etc than you can remove `setSize` call on `JFrame` and call `pack()` on `JFrame` instance before setting visible

Comment: @Ein_Bear and please remember to fill in those missing `super.paintComponent(g);` for all other overidden paintComponent methods, that in itself can cause alot of trouble if its not there

Comment: @MadProgrammer I learnt from reading answers of one of the best :). +1

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Yeah, kleopatra, Hovercraft and mKorbel are pretty aweseome ;)

Comment: That cleared up the null pointer problem, but the pieces still don't show up. I don't think that I have the target canvas set up correctly. Any advice?

Comment: @Ein_Bear where are the pieces added to the board? where are they being drawn?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your variable `board` is not initialized yet. You need to call `setCanvas()` first to initialize it, then you can call `drawPiece()`.